# Every time I rerun my program, the items that I input in my list are reset. Is there a way to save the inputs that are made?

Tags: python, json

Is there a way to save the users/accounts that are created when the program is run? Sorry if this is an easy question, I am just a beginner. Thank you!

The only thing that I have tried is using json.dump to move the accounts to a text file, but it is also reset when I rerun the program.

```
import json

users = {}
login = ""

def menu():
  login = input("Do you have a registered account(yes/no)? ")
  if login == 'yes':
      olduser()
  elif login == 'no':
      newuser()
 

def newuser():
  createlogin = input("create a username: ")

  if createlogin in users:
    print("\nThis username is taken\n")
  else: 
    createpassword = input("create a password: ")
    users[createlogin] = createpassword
    print("\nUser created\n")
    # as requested in comment
    users

    with open('userandpass.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(users)) # use `json.loads` to do the reverse
    
def olduser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")
 
    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
    elif login == "administrator":
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
        print(users)
    else:
        print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password\n")
```

Comment: You need to look up how to save data outside your program, such as dumping it to a file.

Comment: If you save something to file, then you also need to load it at the beginning to apply what has been saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `json.dump()` instead of writing.

```
import json

def newuser():
  createlogin = input("create a username: ")

  if createlogin in users.keys():
    print("\nThis username is taken\n")
  else: 
    createpassword = input("create a password: ")
    users[createlogin] = createpassword
    print("\nUser created\n")
    # as requested in comment
    users

    json.dump(users, open('save/file/path', 'w')) # Saves users to your chosen file
```

Then, you can use `json.load()` to load the data.

```
import json

users = {}
login = ""

try: # To check if any existing data already exists.
    users = json.load(open('save/file/path', 'r'))
except:
    print("No data exists.")

def menu():
  login = input("Do you have a registered account(yes/no)? ")
  if login == 'yes':
      olduser()
  elif login == 'no':
      newuser()
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the help but when I did your edits, I tried making an account and then re-running the program to log in with the previously made account and it still said, "User doesn't exist or wrong password." Could you help me please?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I realized that too.  Try using a for loop that goes through the dictionary `users`, and check if `createlogin` is in `user.keys()`

Comment: One last thing, actually remove the for loop and just use `if createlogin in users.keys():` on the line where you want to check if the username is taken. Next, copy and paste the `try` and `except` parts in `menu()` and paste them on top of your `menu()` function (outside of the `menu()` function). After that, your code should work now.

Comment: Could you expand on that for me? Sorry if this is basic stuff.

Comment: To check if a username is taken, you'll need to check the `users` dictionary's keys. The username is technically the key in this case. So to check if the key (or username) exists, you do `if createlogin in users.keys():`. Next, when checking if there's existing user data, it has to be outside `menu()`. I'm not sure why myself, but I found that it would reset `users` back to empty. When I put it on top of `menu()`, it didn't reset. I updated the code for you in case you didn't know.